# MCMC Gamma Distribution

Tags: self-study, markov-chain-montecarlo, gamma-distribution

I am applyig a MCMC simulation with a Gamma distribution. I am trying to simulate the rainfall in a city using data collected during 1000 days.

First step is to simulate the "data colleceted during 1000 days" that follows a Gamma distribution with $mean = shape * scale = 2 * 2 = 4$.

```
data <- rgamma(1000, shape, rate = 1/scale)
```

Second step is to prepare the prior and likelihood of gamma distrubiton. I created two functions to give support to my MCMC code:

```
# Log Gamma - Prioris
prioriGamma <- function(theta, lambda, nu){
  out <- (lambda-1)*log(theta) - theta*nu
  return(out)
}

# Likelihood Gamma
verossiGamma <- function(nArg, AlphaArg, BetaArg, dadosArg){
  verossi <- nArg*AlphaArg*log(BetaArg) - nArg*lgamma(AlphaArg) + (AlphaArg-1)*sum(log(dadosArg))
  return(verossi)
}
```

Then I code the MCMC simulation:

```
mcmc <- function(y, iter, sigma.rw, lambda.alpha, lambda.beta, nu.alpha, nu.beta, initAlpha, initBeta) {
  # # Parametros temp
  # y = data; sigma.rw = 1; lambda.alpha = 1; lambda.beta = 1; nu.alpha = 1; nu.beta = 1
  # 
  # find n from the data (ie the number of observations)
  n <- length(y)
  
  # first create a table which will store the samples; first column will be alpha, second will be beta
  out <- matrix(NA, nrow=iter, ncol=6)
  
  # initial values
  alpha.cur <- initAlpha
  beta.cur <- initBeta
  out[1,] <- c(alpha.cur, beta.cur, 0, 0, 0, 0)
  
  # mcmc loop starts here
  for (i in 2:iter) {

    ###############
    # update alpha (assume beta is fixed)
    ###############
    
    # propose a new value for alpha
    alpha.can <- rnorm(1, alpha.cur, sigma.rw)
    
    # if it is negative reject straight away else compute the M-H ratio
    if (alpha.can > 0) {
      
      # evaluate the loglikelihood at the current values of alpha.
      loglik.cur <- verossiGamma(n, alpha.cur, beta.cur, y) 
      
      # compute the log-likelihood at the candidate value of alpha
      loglik.can <- verossiGamma(n, alpha.can, beta.cur, y) 
  
      
      # log prior densities
      log.prior.alpha.cur <- prioriGamma(alpha.cur, lambda.alpha, nu.alpha)
      log.prior.alpha.can <- prioriGamma(alpha.can, lambda.alpha, nu.alpha)
      
      logpi.cur <- loglik.cur + log.prior.alpha.cur
      logpi.can <- loglik.can + log.prior.alpha.can
      
      # M-H ratio
      
      # draw from a U(0,1)
      u <- runif(1)
      
      if (log(u) < logpi.can - logpi.cur) {
        alpha.cur <- alpha.can
      }
    }
    
    ###############
    # update beta
    ###############
    
    beta.cur <- rgamma(1, alpha.cur*n + lambda.beta, rate = sum.y + nu.beta)  
    
    # store the samples
    out[i,] <- c(alpha.cur, beta.cur, loglik.cur, loglik.can, log.prior.alpha.cur, log.prior.alpha.can)
    
  }
  
  return(out)
}
```

Where I input gamma data simulated, `lambda` and `nu` of my alpha gamma prior distribution, `lambda` and `nu` of my beta gamma distribution, and two initials values for my Markov Chain.

Apparently the code is working well. Nevertheless, I am facing challenge in the theorical sense to understand exactly what is happening in the simulation. Due to that I have couple questions that I need some help.

1. Why is the Gamma Distribution appropriate to the problem? I understand that Gamma has a relationship with Poisson and Exponential distribution, making sense to use it to simulate couting process. Nevertheless I would like to understand better why is this usefull for the rainfall simulation.
2. What values should I pick up to use in the MCMC simulation?

   res <- mcmc(y = data, iter = 10000, sigma.rw = 1, lambda.alpha = 1, lambda.beta = 1, nu.alpha = 1, nu.beta = 1, initAlpha =  6, initBeta =  2)

When I choose the values of the gamma distribution I did  know that my mean should be around 4. But I don't which values should I use for the prioris lambda.alpha, lambda.beta, nu.alpha, and nu.beta in order to simulate correctly my belives about the data.

I realised that indeppendly of the init values I used, the MCMC converges to the true parameters.

The code I used from this source
https://www.maths.nottingham.ac.uk/plp/pmztk/files/MCMC2-Seattle/Lab-Sessions/2/tutorial_gamma.html

I did some small changes to adapt for myself and I applied into a practial problem to work my theorical understanding of the problem.

Thank you for your support!

Comment: More than the R code is borrowed from [Theo's notes](https://www.maths.nottingham.ac.uk/plp/pmztk/files/MCMC2-Seattle/Lab-Sessions/2/tutorial_gamma.html): the whole Bayesian model is, along with the specific Metropolis-within-Gibbs resolution. It is thus unclear why the generic framework of the tutorial would apply to the application chosen by the OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The question is not about the MCMC method, is not about the R code, but is rather about [Bayesian inference](http://amzn.to/2kxykkw).**

The sampling model is a Gamma model$$x_1,\ldots,x_n \sim \mathcal Ga(\alpha,\beta)$$whose parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are unknown and inferred from the data $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ using Bayesian inference.

The specific prior distribution on the parameter $(\alpha,\beta)$ is made of two Gamma distributions:$$\alpha \sim \mathcal Ga(\lambda_\alpha,\nu_\alpha)\qquad \beta \sim \mathcal Ga(\lambda_\beta,\nu_\beta)$$

The MCMC algorithm reproduce therein is a Metropolis-within-Gibbs algorithm that produces a Markov chain converging to the true posterior distribution
$$\pi(\alpha,\beta|x_1,\ldots,x_n,\lambda_\alpha,\nu_\alpha,\lambda_\beta,\nu_\beta)$$

*(Disclaimer: this is explained in more details in the tutorial written by [Theo Kypraios](https://www.maths.nottingham.ac.uk/plp/pmztk/files/MCMC2-Seattle/Lab-Sessions/2/tutorial_gamma.html), I just did not check the link before answering!)*

### Question 1: Why is the Gamma Distribution appropriate?

The Gamma distribution appears three times, as a sampling distribution and as two prior distributions. There may be a particular reason for picking a Gamma as the distribution of the data, but the other two Gammas are choices of prior distributions, hence do not correspond to a "truth". They may reflect [some prior knowledge](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/12888/7224), or else be chosen for computational convenience. In particular, the Gamma prior on $\beta$ is a [conjugate prior](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/227035/7224), meaning the posterior is also a Gamma distribution. In any case, the MCMC algorithm is adapted to this specific choice of prior (and all choices of $(\lambda_\alpha,\nu_\alpha,\lambda_\beta,\nu_\beta)$ and would obviously need be modified for other classes of priors. When mentioning "the MCMC converges to the true parameters" it should be stated as converging *to the true posterior*.

### Question 2: What values should I pick up to use in the MCMC simulation?

As stated above, the algorithm formally operates the same for all values of the hyperparameter $(\lambda_\alpha,\nu_\alpha,\lambda_\beta,\nu_\beta)$. And the outcome of the MCMC algorithm is reflecting this choice. Changing the hyperparameter and re-running the MCMC algorithm does not bring any information on the choice of these.

Comment: why do I apply MC to alpha parameter and Gibbs Sampler for beta paramters?

Comment: You are free to use a Metropolis-Hastings step for the $\beta$ parameter. Using the exact conditional distribution avoids calibrating this Metropolis-Hastings step.